# Using rewrite engine to route domains to paths on one DocumentRoot

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

I have two domains:

```
domain1.com
domain2.com
```

I have one Apache 2 server, with a document root `/svr.`

I want the following to occur:

- `domain1.com` routes to the equivalent of `/svr/examplepath/thisisadir/param/domain1`
- `domain2.com` routes to the equivalent of `/svr/examplepath/thisisadir/param/domain2`

I have tried using a `.htaccess` with RewriteEngine in `/svr,` using VirtualHost declarations in sites-available for each hostname and simply using 301 redirects. However, I can't use a simple 301, as the user should still see `domain1.com` in their browser.

I.e. `domain1.com/about-this-site` should map to `/svr/examplepath/thisisadir/param/domain1/about-this-site.`

I can't get RewriteEngine to route the hostnames to their respective endpoints, any advice would be much appreciated. I'm currently attempting to use `HTTP_HOST` in a `.htaccess` in the server root, but the rewrite rules still aren't taking effect.

Ilmiont

Comment: "using VirtualHost declarations in sites-available for each hostname" - and what was the problem with this? Using a VirtualHost container would seem to be the preferred solution here (although with _different_ DocumentRoots), as Jonah states in his answer. Is the "one DocumentRoot" a requirement here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop using .htaccess and RewriteEngine, and look instead at the apache directive called "VirtualHost":

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html

This is the problem they solve. Apache will match the incoming Host: header to the ServerName directives in the VirtualHost blocks and apply the configuration from matching VirtualHost. Each VirtualHost can have its own DocumentRoot.

The below can be the skeleton of a solution:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName domain1.com
   DocumentRoot /svr/examplepath/thisisadir/param/domain1
   # other configuration here
 </VirtualHost>
 <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName domain2.com
   DocumentRoot /svr/examplepath/thisisadir/param/domain2
   # other configuration here
 </VirtualHost>
```